# How do I locate my fonts?

Tags: fonts

On older Ubuntus I remember that I always used to have a hidden ".fonts" folder in my Home folder. Now, in Ubuntu 16.10, there is none and I can't find my fonts anywhere. How can I find them? I'm trying to add a custom Unicode symbol to one of my fonts, but to do that I need to open a font file in FontForge.

I've tried to search my computer (for example by typing font's name "Linux Libertine") and absolutely no results...

Comment: You can locate linux libertine font by just using this command `fc-list | grep -i linux`